# How to handle multiple window issue using Selenium Webdriver and Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am unable to identify the objects on the child window. Getting Error as:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to find the element with id == ...
```

I am following below process:

1. Login to window
2. Click on the link--New window pops up.

How to identify the objects on the new window (child window). Some code snippet would be helpful.

Comment: Add some delay before the failing line.

Comment: first, check whether it is a new window or iframe. you can use switch_to method once you identify the window/iframe, and then find the element. Add the code that you tried and relevant HTML code

Comment: @Eugene - Have already added delay of 30 sec.
How to check whether its a window or frame? Switch_to method is not working.

Comment: It is very hard to say without seeing the actual page. Is that a public page you can share?

Comment: @Eugene - Its a corporate internal website, so cannot share the page. Its a frame. So, how to identify it or how to switch to that frame?